# How to extract text between two separators in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a vector of strings like so:

```
mystr <- c("./10g/13.9264.csv", "./6g/62.0544.csv")
```

I only want the part between the two forward slashes, i.e., "10g" and "6g".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `sub()` here with a capture group:

```r
mystr <- c("./10g/13.9264.csv", "./6g/62.0544.csv")
sub(".*/([^/]+)/.*", "\\1", mystr)

[1] "10g" "6g"
```

Answer (score 2):

similar to Tim Biegeleisen, but with a lookbehind and lookahead, using `srt_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
mystr <- c("./10g/13.9264.csv", "./6g/62.0544.csv")

str_extract(mystr,"(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/)")

[1] "10g" "6g"
```

Answer (score 1):

More simply you can capitalize on the fact that the desired substring is one or more digits followed by literal `g`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(mystr, "\\d+g")
[1] "10g" "6g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few alternatives.  They use no packages and the first two do not use any regular expressions.

```
basename(dirname(mystr))
## [1] "10g" "6g"

read.table(text = mystr, sep = "/")[[2]]
## [1] "10g" "6g"

trimws(trimws(mystr,, "[^/]"),, "/")
## [1] "10g" "6g"
```

We could also reformulate these using pipes

```
mystr |> dirname() |> basename()
## [1] "10g" "6g"

read.table(text = mystr, sep = "/") |> (`[[`)(2)
## [1] "10g" "6g" 

mystr |> trimws(,  "[^/]") |> trimws(, "/")
## [1] "10g" "6g"
```

### Note

From the question the input is

```
mystr <- c("./10g/13.9264.csv", "./6g/62.0544.csv")
```

Comment: I love the read.table trick, super clever!